# I am getting an error in mysql update query using inner join

Tags: mysql

I have got an error in running this query in phpMyadmin. The query is to update a table using inner join .Pls help me

My tables are  :

> userpswd

- ID
- password
- Name
- Col 4
- Col 5
- index
- oncampus_present ( the colum I want to update )

> oncampus

- index
- ID

I already have gone through most of the threads given here regarding the same and none seem to work.

```
UPDATE userpswd
SET oncampus_present='yes'
FROM userpswd
INNER JOIN oncampus
ON userpswd.ID=oncampus.ID
WHERE userpswd.oncampus_present=NULL
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM userpswd
            INNER JOIN oncampus
            ON userpswd.ID=oncam' at line 3

Comment: That error message SHOULD have been posted in your question before pressing the Ask button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your SQL syntax

Try This

```
UPDATE userpswd
INNER JOIN oncampus
ON userpswd.ID=oncampus.ID
SET oncampus_present='yes'
WHERE userpswd.oncampus_present IS NULL
```